# Sencha touch equivalent of iOS UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit

Tags: html, extjs, sencha-touch

I'm looking for a Sencha Touch equivalent of iOS UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit. As simple as that.

I have an Image component which I want to fit it's width and height to it's container and maintain aspect ratio while doing so.

by fitting to it's container I mean maximizing it as possible without having it cut off anywhere, all parts of the image should remain visible on the screen.

How can it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to use CSS...check out the background-size 'contain' and 'cover' settings. You can define a class then apply it to your component

:-)

Comment: Thanks, can you give a tiny 'inline' snippet of how to do that with CSS? Let's say I have an `Ext.Panel` component that contains an `{xtype: 'image'}` component...

Comment: I ended up with the following ext image component: 
`{
   xtype:'image',
   style:'div' +
   '{'   +
       'background-repeat:no-repeat;' +
       'background-size:contain;' +
   '}'
}`